# Convert Long Excel Worksheet Formula to VBA formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to count records within a single date/ day. The field I count is formatted as:

```
"m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

The following formula work just fine on the worksheet

```
=COUNTIFS(Database!B:B,">="&DATE(YEAR(RFQReceived),MONTH(RFQReceived),DAY(RFQReceived)) + TIME(0,0,0),Database!B:B,"<="&DATE(YEAR(RFQReceived),MONTH(RFQReceived),DAY(RFQReceived))+TIME(23,59,59))
```

I tried the following on VBA but give me Type mismatch Error. How to write it correctly on the VBA format?

```
RecordNum = Evaluate("COUNTIFS(Database!B:B,">="&DATE(YEAR(RFQReceived),MONTH(RFQReceived),DAY(RFQReceived)) + TIME(0,0,0),Database!B:B,"<="&DATE(YEAR(RFQReceived),MONTH(RFQReceived),DAY(RFQReceived))+TIME(23,59,59))")
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double the `"`

```
RecordNum = Evaluate("COUNTIFS(Database!B:B,"">=""&DATE(YEAR(RFQReceived),MONTH(RFQReceived),DAY(RFQReceived)) + TIME(0,0,0),Database!B:B,""<=""&DATE(YEAR(RFQReceived),MONTH(RFQReceived),DAY(RFQReceived))+TIME(23,59,59))")
```

Comment: no error but it always return 0 which is actually incorrect. What might be wrong?

Comment: @Khalif Are you sure that formula works fine on the worksheet?

Comment: @Khalif I just dummied up some data (created a sheet called "Database", put some date/times in column B, created a named range called `RFQReceived` in another cell, put a date in that cell) then ran the code, and got the same answer as I did by typing your original formula into another cell.